# Android: make call service thread-safe

Tags: android, multithreading, android-intent

I have a loop which do call to service:

```
context.startService(intent);
```

In and want to get back the result after the service finish its processing for each request. So I pass an unique id to intent to be able to distinguish the response.

But unfortunately, the startService which call to onStartCommand is not thread-safe. This leads to the response is always the last id, as the intent was changed in later call.

The service code is similar:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    protected Bundle rcvExtras;

    @Override            
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        rcvExtras = intent.getExtras();
        // Todo with information in rcv Extra
        BaseRestClient restClient = new BaseRestClient(rcvExtras.getString(Constants.INTENT_KEY_OBJECT_TYPE));
        restClient.post(data, rcvExtras.getString(Constants.INTENT_KEY_URL), new CallBackHandler(this)); // This is an async call
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private class CallBackHandler extends Handler {
        private final WeakReference<MyService> myServiceRef;

        public CallBackHandler(MyService myService) {
            myServiceRef = new WeakReference<>(myService);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Intent result = new Intent(Constants.WS_CALL_BACK);
            rcvExtras.putInt(Constants.INTENT_KEY_STATUS, msg.what);
            result.putExtras(rcvExtras);
            log.info("Broadcast data");
            sendBroadcast(result); // Broadcast result, actually the caller will get this broadcast message.

            MyService myService = myServiceRef.get();
            log.info("Stopping service");
            myService.stopSelf(startId);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make service calling thread-safe?

Comment: Could someone please help me?

Comment: Yes, this is all my code, no others related one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see your problem, this is programatic issue not caused by framework. Here from you call startService until you call stopself, your MyService is singleton, and your rcvExtras is a global variable and will be shared between threads.

It is simple to fix:

- Move the declaration of rcvExtras to method scope, here is onStartCommand.
- Extend the CallBackHandler to allow your rcvExtras, and use it once callback.

At this time you do not have any varable can be shared, and you safe.

Hope this help.

Comment: Ah, yes, you save my life, thank you very much. A stupid stub of code.